# disable address bar and back and forward button of browser

Tags: javascript

how can I disable or hide address bar and back and forward buttons in ie and firefox

i tried lots of links and solutions but non of them worked
for example for disabling back button:

```
<script type = "text/javascript" >
function changeHashOnLoad() {
    window.location.href += "#";
    setTimeout("changeHashAgain()", "50");
}

function changeHashAgain() {
    window.location.href += "1";
}

var storedHash = window.location.hash;
window.setInterval(function () {
    if (window.location.hash != storedHash) {
        window.location.hash = storedHash;
    }
}, 50);
```

but it seems that it goes to previous page then it returns

and i trid :

```
 window.scrollTo(0, 0); // reset in case prev not scrolled  
        var nPageH = $(document).height();
        var nViewH = window.outerHeight;
        if (nViewH > nPageH) {
            nViewH -= 250;
            $('BODY').css('height', nViewH + 'px');
        }
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }
```

for disabling menu bar but it didnt work

what can i do

Comment: Describe please what you exactly want to do with it, so we can better help you.

Comment: as I said i want to hide address bar and back and forward buttons

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't think you can disable buttons on browser. I mean, otherwise, we'd seen it on spyware infected sites...

In terms of hiding them, I've seen banks use a full screen [popup](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html) without those buttons (but hardware button on mouse or hitting backspace still works).

Comment: @addrakadabra: just like i said in comment on 29 Feb at hashchange solution (window.open())

Answer (score 1):

Instead of disabling the back button, try to make your page that supports users to going back. It will increase the  usability of your application.

Even you can impliment it for the ajax activities also.

Comment: I have to, when your sub director FORCE you to do some thing, you cant tell him Its not good or it would decrease usability of the application

Comment: @Adrakadabra: Different browsers behave differently, and at least in Firefox you cannot hide the address bar.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but you can bind to the window's hashchange event.

For example, in jQuery it very easy to do:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function(e)
{
 e.stopImmediatePropagation();
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();

 return false; // stop event
});
```

The result is that the back button not changes the page when an anchor is in the url. But i agree with the first answer also (it is not a real answer i think, it is an advice).

You can also override the last entry in window.history, so user can't go back.

Comment: But what exactly do you want to try to do? You can hide (in the meaning of the word hide) the backbutton and menubar by pressing F11 in your browser. Otherwise go for window.open if you don't you want buttons and other browser stuff. or simply don't use hashes.